# SSIS Conditional Split not working as intended

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS job as follows:

[image]

The split is as follows:
[image]

Lookup settings:
[image]

[image]

I'm only looking against the ticketId in both source/destination.

The issue is that out of the 2288, many should be new rows which don't exist in the destination DB but it seems like they all go to the Update condition instead.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Please expand Look up transformation and add screen shot if you can please

Comment: Settings have been added above. And I'm just thinking if RecordNotExists = ISNULL(TicketId) is looking at the source DB because that will always have a TicketId, it is the destination which will not.

Comment: Lookup has a no-match output. Why are you using a conditional as well? Did you encounter errors perhaps, and though `Redirect to no match` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is looking at source TicketID, you would have to expose TickedID from lookup and then check this against NULL.

[image]

After that you need to change conditions to:

- ISNULL(LKP_TicketId)
- !ISNULL(LKP_TicketId)

Also @Jayvee has a valid point that you can skip conditional split completely and redirect rows directly from lookup.

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the conditional. Just do the lookup redirecting the not-found tickets to added row count.

Comment: Definitely, much less SSISing.

Answer (score -1):

Conditions has to be specified clearly , this transformation is looking at all Ticketid's instead of a case statement. SO its writing all towards update

```
1) isnull(TicketID) != isnull(TicketID)  -- record not exists

2) isnull(TicketID) == isnull(TicketID)  -- Record exists
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense `this transformation is looking at all Ticketid's instead of a case statement` what does that mean? As for the expressions, they are comparing the return value of the same functino to itself. The first will always be false, the second always true